# MySQL + PHP search and return multiple types

Tags: php, mysql, search

My goals is returning multiple types from a search query. I have two tables of users and movies. If search query is 'Mat', i should return both results for users with name like '%mat%' and movies with title '%mat%'.

I can use UNION or JOIN two tables in one request, but i guess there will be ordering problem.

For example i have this structure:

Users table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Mat |

Movies table:

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Matrix |
| 2 | Matilda |

Search query - "mat". Logically, i guess i should get user first, then two others movies. Also, there can be inverse situation where i should get movies first, and users. What is the best solution? I can make two separate requests for users and movies and then combine them into one array with 50/50 limit of each other, but i guess this is not the optimal solution.

Comment: This might be easier when using the same column names... and a synthetic column, which indicates the source table - else it's impossible to tell later what eg. `id 1` means.

Comment: `i guess there will be ordering problem`...you could wrap the result of the union in an outer query and order that.

Comment: If i return the same column (select id FROM users WHERE lower(name) LIKE '%Matrix%') UNION (SELECT id FROM movies WHERE LOWER(title) LIKE '%Matrix%' order by num_of_plays DESC) LIMIT 10 i guess i have correct data, but i should know which table i get request from (user or movie)

Comment: Adding extra column to each request has solved this issue